# How to Catch Kill process in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that is run from the Windows Task Scheduler. If the powershell process is killed from either Task Scheduler or Task Manager, I would like to catch that in my powershell script, log some stuff then let the process die.

How do I do this?

Comment: When a process is [*terminated*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040722-00/?p=38373) (e.g. via Task Manager's `Processes` tab as opposed to `Applications`) it doesn't receive any notifications. But I guess you can spawn another watchdog process.

Comment: If someone kills my powershell script, I want to catch that event as well so I can ignore it. Users should never need to quit my script, they could only do that by mistake, so it would only be appropriate if I could override their actions.

Comment: When someone actively kills your process, you don't get the chance to do any cleanup. Only solution I know of is to implement transaction logic like databases do. You could persist certain steps to disk and on restarting check if the "transaction" completed or if you need to cleanup.